# Encapsulating Content In a Variable

Tags: perl, variables, encapsulation

I want to know how can I encapsulate the result(`substr($text, 12)`) of the variable `$opt` into itself(put the result replacing the expression `substr($text, 12)`), but how I can do this?

If needed. Here is my code:

```
my $text;
my $opt = substr($text, 12);
if ($command =~ /^Hello World Application/i) {
    print "$opt\n";
}
# More code....
print # Here I want to print the result of 'substr($text, 12)' in the if
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details. I don't understand why you can't simply `print substr($text, 12);`

Comment: @Ivan: Because I need to store this in a variable to use it after the if **;)**

Comment: @Nathan => Can you post example code (including initializing your strings) that doesn't work the way you want?  With the above code, its not clear what isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to create an anonymous subroutine that captures the behaviour and references that you want but you don't run until you need it:

```
my $text;  # not yet initialized
my $substr = sub { substr( $text, 12 ) };  # doesn't run yet

... # lots of code, initializing $text eventually

my $string = $substr->(); # now get the substring;
```

Comment: Brian. You're the guy! I've already imported all your books since two days **;)**

Answer (score 4):

```
my $text;
my $opt = substr($text, 12);
```

...will give undef errors when you use `use strict; use warnings;` -- is this what you intend? You seem to be missing some code. You're using three different variable names: `$text`, `$opt`, and `$command` but do you intend these all to be the same value?

Perhaps this is what you intend, but without more information it's hard to tell:

```
if ($command =~ /^Hello World Application/i)
{
    print substr($command, 12);
}
```

...but that will always just print `Hello World`, so you don't really even need to use a `substr`.

**EDIT**: You still haven't edited your question to give a real example, but you seem to want to be able to modify a variable from inside an `if` block and then access it outside the `if` block. You can do that by simply ensuring that the variable is declared outside the `if` block:

```
my $variable;
if (something...)
{
    $variable = "something else";
}
```

Please read about "variable scope" at [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements).

Comment: I'm using strict and warnings, but that is only a snippet. My code have 452 lines.

Comment: The snippet you have provided doesn't really make sense, so you will need to add clarification.

Comment: This is a test, but how I can that into the variable and print it outside the if?

Comment: I still don't understand the question :)